# Solr search on a field with ReverseStringFilterFactory return 0 records for reverse input

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a requirement where user should able to get same result when searched with a String in reversed or striaght for
example: q="F44" or q="44F" should result same result.

I have created a new field "text_rev" which is assigned to below Field Type.
And I did Copy field with actual/original field "retailId"

```
<copyField source="retailId" dest="text_rev"/>

<fieldType name="text_rvsstr" class="solr.TextField"><analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/><filter class="solr.ReverseStringFilterFactory"/></analyzer></fieldType>
```

when I search with q=text_rev:F44 i get the result but when i search with q=text_rev:44F i get 0 results.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Those searches are on the same field.  Searching the reverse direction is only going to work on the reversed field, and searching the forward direction is only going to work on the original field.

By searching both fields for the same information, you can check both directions in one query.

q=retailId:F44 OR text_rev:F44

Comment: just to understand, what does my analyzer do. my understanding was it will first splits the text field into tokens and transform the tokens by reversing the string and store it to index. please correct me

Comment: What gets *stored* is always the exact text received, analysis does not affect that.  The *indexed* data is subject to the configured analysis, though.

Your analysis chain will split the input into terms, and then the reverse filter will be applied to each of those terms.  The result will go into the search index, but not into stored data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search both fields. Also, if you actually expect to search in reverse, you need to have asymmetric index and query-type definition. Otherwise your term will get reversed both during indexing and querying and you effectively loose any reason to do so.

You can test that by using Analyse screen of the Admin UI and providing content in both boxes. It will then show how the terms get processed and matched during indexing/querying.